# TikZ: Key to the \draw command to modify the inside nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting

Suppose I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=6]
\tikzstyle{xthick} = [thick, |-|]
\tikzstyle{xthin} = []
%
\draw[xthick](.93,-.6)node[left]{\bfseries 00\,00\,00\,00\,00}--(1,-.6);
\draw[xthin](1.013,-.625)--(1.082,-.625)node[right]{00\,00\,00\,00\,10};
\draw[xthin](.972,-.65)node[left]{00\,00\,00\,11\,00}--(1.041,-.65);
\draw[xthin](1.054,-.675)--(1.124,-.675)node[right]{00\,00\,00\,11\,10};
\draw[xthick](.901,-.7)node[left]{\bfseries 00\,11\,00\,01\,01}--(.971,-.7);
\draw[xthin](.983,-.725)--(1.053,-.725)node[right]{00\,11\,00\,01\,11};
%
\draw[xthin](.963,-.8)node[left]{00\,00\,00\,00\,00\,00}--(1,-.8);
\draw[xthin](.974,-.825)--(1.012,-.825)node[right]{00\,00\,00\,00\,00\,11};
\draw[xthick](.901,-.85)node[left]{\bfseries 00\,11\,00\,01\,01\,01}--(.938,-.85);
\draw[xthin](.977,-.875)--(1.015,-.875)node[right]{00\,11\,00\,01\,01\,10};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I would like to a code with the very same output, just without the need for `\bfseries`. Is is possible to make the `xthick` key of `\draw` modify the nested `node`s?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify options like `\bfseries` using the `font` key:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=6]
\tikzset{
    xthick/.style = {thick, |-|, font=\bfseries},
    xthin/.style = {}
}
%
\draw[xthick](.93,-.6)node[left]{00\,00\,00\,00\,00}--(1,-.6);
\draw[xthin](1.013,-.625)--(1.082,-.625)node[right]{00\,00\,00\,00\,10};
\draw[xthin](.972,-.65)node[left]{00\,00\,00\,11\,00}--(1.041,-.65);
\draw[xthin](1.054,-.675)--(1.124,-.675)node[right]{00\,00\,00\,11\,10};
\draw[xthick](.901,-.7)node[left]{00\,11\,00\,01\,01}--(.971,-.7);
\draw[xthin](.983,-.725)--(1.053,-.725)node[right]{00\,11\,00\,01\,11};
%
\draw[xthin](.963,-.8)node[left]{00\,00\,00\,00\,00\,00}--(1,-.8);
\draw[xthin](.974,-.825)--(1.012,-.825)node[right]{00\,00\,00\,00\,00\,11};
\draw[xthick](.901,-.85)node[left]{00\,11\,00\,01\,01\,01}--(.938,-.85);
\draw[xthin](.977,-.875)--(1.015,-.875)node[right]{00\,11\,00\,01\,01\,10};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah cool. (Btw, the problem of manuals: everything is so easy if you know what do you look for.)